# Lost partition while installing Ubuntu

Tags: partitioning, data-loss

I am new to Ubuntu.

Earlier I was using window 7 and had 2 drives. A few minutes back I installed Ubuntu 13.10 on my laptop. While installing, I selected the "replace Windows 7" option, and now I can see only 1 drive. This is output of fdisk.

```
vishal@Ghost-PC:~$ sudo fdisk -lu

Disk /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0002ad36

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048   968800255   484399104   83  Linux
/dev/sda2       968802302   976771071     3984385    5  Extended
/dev/sda5       968802304   976771071     3984384   82  Linux swap / Solaris
```

I think I lost my other drive. Please confirm how to recover that drive, because the drive is very important.

Comment: Use The (Disks) Graphical Program to get a better picture about you your disk and post a screenshot using (Screenshot) utility if you get any problems using Disks

Comment: If you had two *partitions* not drives, then when you chose to use the whole drive to install Ubuntu, it got rid of all existing partitions on that drive.

Answer (score 0):

Open your home folder and see if the drive is in the list on the left side if its not you will have to probably mount the drive manually via terminal.

Edit@
Is your HDD discoverable in the BIOS/UEFI?